# Regex time duration

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to find a match for a strText on any date in a file,  than I want to add range of 50 to 60 seconds to that time and see if that strText appeared again on the line. 
Following regex works fine. But on Second date it is checking for any time strText has appeared again not 4o to 50 seconds.

```
string regex =
        @"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})[^\n\r]+?strText.+?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d  {2}:\d{2})[^\n\r]+?strText";
```

So on second date I need to add range of 40 and 50 seconds. Any ideas how to do that. It doesn't have to be regex but I thought it could be easier with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex has no concept of numbers, so hassling with dynamically changing the expression to find the exact times you are looking for would be needlessly complicated.

Instead, I see no reason not to just:

- Parse the string manually after it has been retrieved with the regex expression
- Run the number crunching (adding time) with [datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx).
- Store the expected time and compare if it matches on the second check.